# Architecture of telegram bot for 150k users simultaneously

Tags: architecture, telegram, telegram-bot, high-load, tdlib

I am going to create a telegram bot to handle 150k users simultaneously (per second).

I am going to use TDLib (because I do want to face Telegram Bot API limits about 30 messages per second).

Previously I always used Telegram Bot Webhook. I registered webhook to point on my server.
And my server handles requests from Telegram and sends messages to users. I had no any loading on my server. Max loading is 10 or 30 users per second.

Now I am going to use TDLib. So interactions by architecture.

### Interaction 1. Telegram Webhook + TDLib

It doesn't work because in logs of nginx I see that nginx doesn't receive any webhook requests when TDLib is running.

### Interaction 2. Several instances of TDLib

It works. Every instance can send message and get updates. But I am worry about network traffic because every instance will get all updates.

### Interaction 3. One instance of TDLib (SELECTED CURRENTLY)

One instance of TDLib gets all updates and just sends it to the queue (lets call it as **in.queue**).

I will write a program to handle the updates from the queue **in.queue**.

The processing of the update from the queue is create a response command and post it to another queue (**out.queue**).

The TDLib instance listens **out.queue** and applies command.

---

But I want to know how I could test my bot before deploying on prod.

Does it possible to somehow emulate such loading (150k users simultaneously) to test my architecture?

Comment: 150k users simultaneously? wtf? 
Anyway, TDLib is the best choice, because it creates a direct TCP tunnel between you and Telegram. I think you should write to @BotSupport because this is a very edgy case, maybe you can work out a solution. 
PS: Have you tried Webhooks with a load balancer?

Comment: @MarcoBuster thank you for your response. I decided to use TDLib anyway.

About load balancer. It helps to hold the users but it fails with Telegram limits by sending messages to users. Yes I can use direct response but when I want to do "send some message to every user" I will face with the Telegram Bot API limits (30 messages per second).

Comment: When you send "global" messages to many users you should slow down and sleep every n, if the timing is not so important. With a very large userbase it can take days but it's the only way. Again, maybe if you explain your situation to [@]BotSupport they could help you by removing some API limits.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure using TdLib instead of BOT.Api don't hit the telegram limits?
do you reach any improvement?